# php mail From: & Reply-to: headers issue

Tags: php, email, header

Ok so I am writing a php contact form that will send two emails. One to the webmaster with the info and a similar confirmation email sent to the form submitter.

The problem is with the confirmation email. I am trying to configure the From: header and the Reply-to: but and for some reason catching a hurdle.

Originally I had my php set up as so declaring each header parameter...

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$guests = $_POST['guests'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="THIS IS A FORM SUBMISSION FROM domain.COM... \n \n PARTY INQUIRY \n \n From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n # of Guests: $guests \n Type: $type \n Date Requested: $month $day, $year \n \n Additional Info: $message";
$comfirmcontent="THIS IS A CONFIRMATION OF YOUR FORM SUBMISSION TO domain.COM... \n \n PARTY INQUIRY \n \n From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n # of Guests: $guests \n Type: $type \n Date Requested: $month $day, $year \n \n Additional Info: $message \n\n\n If you have any further questions please email info@mydomain.com";
$confirmsubject="Confirmation for your inquiry to mydomain.COM";
$confirmheader="From: mydomain.com" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: info@mydomain.com" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
$recipient = "info@domain.com";
$subject = "Party Inquiry from Website";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
mail($email, $confirmsubject, $comfirmcontent, $confirmheader) or die("Error!");
header('Location: party-form-thank-you.html')
```

This as I understand is the proper way, but I am still having the From: say "mydomain.com@myhostdomain.com as both the senders name and senders email. Which is how it was before I even declared the headers and it was null.

So then I tried an override using

```
mail($email, $confirmsubject, $comfirmcontent, $confirmheader,'-finfo@mydomain.com') or die("Error!");
```

Which returned the same results.

So I have resorted to simply using the following, w/o declared headers.

```
mail($email, $confirmsubject, $comfirmcontent, null,'-finfo@mydomain.com') or die("Error!");
```

This give me the proper from/reply-to address, but also puts it as the senders name.

So my question is if there is any way to write the headers so the email formulates as such:

Senders Name: myDomain.com

Senders Email: info@mydomain.com

Comment: Yep, it's all in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: If you are referring to this code from that manual, it is what I originally coded. As you can see in my post.


    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Comment: You need to dig deeper into it ;-)

Comment: `From:` should be an email address. You're not providing one - you're just slapping in a domain name. `From: foo@example.com` - good. `From: example.com` - bad.

Comment: actually 
    `$fromname="mydomain.com";`
    `$fromemail="info@mydomain.com";`
    `'From: "' . $fromname . '" <' . $fromemail . '>`
works perfectly to show Sender Name & Sender Email which is how I want it

Comment: As I mentioned if I use From: foo@example.com the email will display the sender as foo@example.com@myhostsserver.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use an array for my headers, then [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) them on "\r\n":

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";';
$headers[] = 'Date: ' . date('r', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
$headers[] = 'Message-ID: <' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . (empty($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ? '' : '@' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) . '>';

// here is the from and reply-to part:
$headers[] = 'From: "' . $fromName . '" <' . $fromAddress . '>';
$headers[] = 'Reply-To: "' . $replyToName . '" <' . $replyToAddress . '>';
$headers[] = 'X-Mailer: PHP v' . phpversion();
if (!empty($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'])) {
    $headers[] = 'X-Originating-IP: ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
}

// Use the implode function to collapse the array into a single string
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! This has gotten me almost all the way there.
I tried to implement the same code but without the array as so:

Comment: `$fromname="mydomain.com";
    $fromemail="info@mydomain.com";
    $confirmheader=
'From: "' . $fromname . '" <' . $fromemail . '>';
'Reply-To: "' . $fromname . '" <' . $fromemail . '>';
'X-Mailer: PHP v' . phpversion();
    $recipient = "info@mydomain.com";
    $subject = "Contact From Website";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    mail($email, $confirmsubject, $comfirmcontent, $confirmheader) or die("Error!");
    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html')`

Comment: This has gotten the from name and email to correctly display. However when I reply to the email it doesnt reply to that address, it tries to reply to the recipient?

Comment: The array is nice because you get each entry on one line and don't have to worry about the new line until the end. What is the value of your '$email' and '$fromemail' variables? Also, if you received the confirmation email and replied to that, your from and reply-to are the same.

Comment: Sadly, since I am a front end developer, php is not my forte. So I was trying to streamline it ;) I did in fact receive the confirmation email and tried to reply to it and it replies to myself oddly.

Comment: my variable were $fromname="mydomain.com"; $fromemail="info@mydomain.com";

Comment: Your confirmation header uses the same email for both 'From' and 'Reply-To', so yes, it would reply to yourself if you sent it from info@mydomain.com

Comment: No what is happening is "User" fills out the form. "User" then gets a confirmation email saying it is From: "Website <info@website.com>" Which is correct and perfect. However when you reply to said message it starts the new email To: "User" Thats where I was getting perplexed.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect: ..."'>'; 'Reply"... the Reply-To isn't even in your confirmation header, because you close it with ';'. Each piece of header information needs to be included, separated by a new line, which is why I recommended using the array - it is much easier to see where you went wrong. All the code you need to use the array is included in my answer, or just make sure you tie your string together.

Comment: Ok I see now... So theoretically this should work no?

    `$confirmheader=
'From: "' . $fromname . '" <' . $fromemail . '>'  . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: "' . $fromname . '" <' . $fromemail . '>'  . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP v' . phpversion();`

Comment: Looks that way, but you shouldn't need a 'Reply-To' header if it is the same as the 'From' address. Are you meaning to use a different name and email for the 'Reply-To' ?

Comment: WORKS! Thank you. I will +1 you when my rep is up! Thanks for working through it with me.

Comment: OK now a new problem... As I fill out the form with a gmail address everything works and both emails send to each recipient. For some reason now though, if you fill out the form with a yahoo address it will only send the confirmation email and not the request...

Comment: Please update your question to show your current code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933780/php-mail-and-yahoo-com-not-vibing  updated