# php mail and yahoo.com not vibing

Tags: php, email, yahoo

Ok so Ive recently developed a php contact form for party inquiries.

The form sends one request to the website and one confirmation to the person who fills out the form.

In gmail it seems that both emails are being sent properly. However, if you fill out the form with a yahoo email it will send only the confirmation. Not the request. This is obviously problematic. So I am trying to figure out why.

My php is as follows:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$guests = $_POST['guests'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="msg";
$comfirmcontent="msg";
$fromname="mydomain.com";
$fromemail="info@mydomain.com";
$confirmheader=
'From: "' . $fromname . '" <' . $fromemail . '>'  . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: "' . $fromname . '" <' . $fromemail . '>'  . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP v' . phpversion();
$recipient = "info@mydomain.com";
$subject = "Contact From Website";
$mailheader = "From: $email";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
mail($email, $confirmsubject, $comfirmcontent, $confirmheader) or die("Error!");
header('Location: party-form-thank-you.html')
```

So this email isnt sending from yahoo:

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
```

But this one is:

```
mail($email, $confirmsubject, $comfirmcontent, $confirmheader) or die("Error!");
```

I thought it may be because the

```
'X-Mailer: PHP v' . phpversion();
```

was defined in the confirmation email so I tried writing this into the $mailheader

```
$mailheader = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP v' . phpversion();
```

...Didnt work.

So I am asking you all my coding friends for help as to why.

TIA

Comment: It's possible because in the recipient email, the $recipient and $fromemail are the same. I don't get emails I send to myself in yahoo either, even if it's just a forwarding email. I think you need to set up a generic email like do-not-reply@ for system messages and use that as the sender email instead

Comment: mail($recipient...) is not sending to yahoo because $recipient is "info@mydomain.com". @Kai's point is also very good.

Comment: I see I misstated, the form isnt sending FROM a yahoo address.

$recipient is the webmaster which is @domain. It wont submit the request to the domain if the person filling out the form has a yahoo domain.

Comment: @kaiQing the $recipient and $fromemail are variables in different strings.  Do you think even tho they are sending different emails they should have the variable name?

Comment: ok figured it out, it was the fact those two variables were defined as the same. I rewrote it as this:

Answer (score 0):

@kaiqing

You were correct, since the variables were defined as the same with different name I think yahoo was having a problem,

I rewrote it as this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fromname="BOULETTESLARDER.COM";
$recipient = "info@bouletteslarder.com";
$subject = "Contact From Website";
$mailheader = 'From: "' . $name . '" <' . $email . '>'  . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP v' . phpversion();
$confirmheader=
'From: "' . $fromname . '" <' . $recipient . '>'  . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: "' . $fromname . '" <' . $recipient . '>'  . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP v' . phpversion();
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
mail($email, $confirmsubject, $comfirmcontent, $confirmheader) or die("Error!");
```

Now it will submit and send both emails — to the website & to the user — if a user filling out the form has a yahoo address.